# Problems with Subqueries and Multiple Select Statements SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Use MySQL SAKILA Database to write a SQL statement to List the Film Titles and Category Names of all the films starring Emily Dee. Write the Query as a subquery

So far I have but I am not getting results

```
SELECT title, category.name 
FROM film 
WHERE film_id IN(
        SELECT film_id 
        FROM film_category
        WHERE category_id IN(
                SELECT category_id 
                FROM film_category 
                WHERE film_id IN(
                         SELECT film_id 
                         from film_actor 
                         WHERE actor_id IN(
                                 SELECT actor_id 
                                 FROM actor 
                                 WHERE first_name = 'Lucile' AND last_name = 'Dee'
                                           )
                                  )
                               )
                    );
```